# How change the default volume level of audio in HTML5 without any js?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

if you see me posting questions lately is that I've been struggling with something I've tried and didn't' work at leas 100x of times. Well I saw in this web: http://w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_volume

that you can change the volume of an audio in HTML5, but in an event using javascript.

I was wondering, if i can put the audio in autoplay, hidden, can I set the default volume level to for an example 0.5? I know that 1.0 is the maximum but I want to put the level of my audio in 0.5 as the default volume levelbecause I want to add some other sounds that are needed to be louder than the background music and have an event in javascript.

```
      <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <audio id= "audio1" controls="controls" hidden="true" autoplay>
        <source src="Audio\Jaunty Gumption.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>

    <img src="Image/fondo.png" class='fondo'>

    <style>
    .fondo{
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    </script>

</html>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot, [volume is not an attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#the-audio-element) on the html `audio` element

Comment: So I must use the javascript event to do so?

Comment: Yes, mozilla references that a volume attribute is being added but it's still non standard :(